# Deleting checked row in data table with http request in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a table with data fetched into in from the server. I want to delete a row by ticking or checking the checkboxes and hitting the delete button to remove the row. Below is the code;

Comment: You haven't stated how your code is failing.

Comment: @Aaron, i am stuck with how i would fetch a particular id from the table using my delete request

Comment: I am stuck with how to retrieve id of the selected row so i can use the delete request to remove it

Comment: @AJT_82,  i get an error in my terminal like "property  `selected` does not exist on type {id : number ,first_name, .......}

Comment: the error points at my component.ts file. I can't really rectify why it doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, if you happened to read it before I deleted it. Wait, I'll take a closer look and get back to you, you seem to have a few problems in your code :)

Comment: @AJT_82, Thank you in advance and i would appreciate it

Comment: anyother assistance please

Comment: I'll answer in a bit, just as I get my code written down, found your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'client',
  templateUrl:'client_table.html',
  providers:[HttpService]
  })

export class ClientComponent {

   constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private router: Router){ }
   activeClient: Client; // used as the current chosen client


  deleteClient(){
      this.httpService.deleteCustomer(this.activeClient.id)
        .subscribe(....)
  }

  checkbox(client){
    this.activeClient = client; 
    client.selected = (client.selected) ? false : true;
  }
```

Your template and service looks fine, at least by looking at it. This should work now!

Some comments on your component... since you are importing `Clients` like so:
`import {Clients} from './Client';` to your component, I assume the following is unnecessary in your component.

```
  Clients: {
      id: number,
     first_name:string,
     last_name: string,
     email: string,
     company_name: string,
     mobile: string,
     city: string,
     website:string
  }[];
```

Comment: uncaught exception: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9000/api/crm_api/v1/customers/%7Bcustomer%7D . this is error i get after selecting the checkbox and pressing the delete button

Comment: That means that there is a problem with your url, well you can see that it doesn't give you the customer id in the url, but just `%7Bcustomer%7D`

Comment: try using `${id}` as that is your parameter in the service method.

Comment: return this.http.delete('http://localhost:9000/api/crm_api/v1/customers/${id}')  ..Still 404 error. But why does the terminal keep giving error that " property id does not exist on type 'typeof Clients? I have an id declared tho in my Client.ts file

Comment: could you `console.log(client)` in the checkbox-method, so we can see how the client looks like? Soon we have to continue this in chat, because this thread is getting long. And the 404-error is a whole other issue, and should be raised as a separate question as it isn't the issue in this question ;)

Comment: Object { id: 3, first_name: "Sandy Yeboah ", last_name: "Gaitain", email: "Gaitan@peacemour.com", mobile: "0501346736", company_name: "Halifas Ghana Medi Coporation", city: "Accra- Ghana", website: "Metabo.com", created_at: "2017-01-02 16:35:05", updated_at: "2017-01-02 16:35:05", 1 more… }            This is what is displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132316/discussion-between-ajt-82-and-switz).